# Get different values for each number

Tags: contest-math, multiple-integral

I am trying to get some type of values like this.

```
Value: 200
Days: 35

Division: Value/Days = 5.714 for the total 35 days
```

I am getting fixed value for each day using this way, but I actually want to get different value for each day like:

```
Division: Value/Days = 5.714

Day 1: 5.714
Day 2: 4.5
Day 3: 6.1
Day 4: 3.4
Day 5: 2
Day 6: 5.1

And so on for the total of 35 days.
```

How can I achieve this goal? Is there any way to do so? I am really null in mathematics so i really need an idea from the experts.

Note: I want to acheive this in PHP.

Comment: What contest is this from? Just wondering. This is clearly a programming problem.

Comment: So you want to generate a sequence given it's sum?

Comment: @maciek97x yes but there should be diferent sequence for each day

Comment: @NomiTech you can generate random sequence and then multiply each term by desired sum divided by actual sum.

Comment: @maciek97x please can you give me an example? It will be very helpful to understand. I will really appriciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example code:

```
<?php
function gen_value($day, $days_count, $desired_sum, $prev_values) {
  if ($day == 1) {
    return $desired_sum/$days_count + $desired_sum/$days_count*0.2*rand(-100, 100)/100;
  } elseif ($day < $days_count) {
    $diff = ($desired_sum/$days_count - array_sum($prev_values)/count($prev_values));
    $sign = $diff > 0 ? 1 : -1;
    return abs($desired_sum/$days_count + ($diff +
      $desired_sum/$days_count*0.2*$sign)*rand(0, 200)/100);
  } else {
    return 200 - array_sum($prev_values);
  }
}

$len = 35;
$desired_sum = 200;

$arr = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
  $arr[] = gen_value($i + 1, $len, $desired_sum, $arr);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
  print("$arr[$i]\n");
}
$sum = array_sum($arr);
print("sum = $sum");
```

Result:

```
5.3142857142857
8.5377142857143
2.4178857142857
...
6.1704160030257
sum = 200
```

Comment: Thank you man, you just solved it ☺️ Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark my answer as accepted then.

Comment: Ok I will mark, I need to ask a question related to this answer. Actually I want to do this in the php cron jobs and this cron will run one in a day for 35 days. If I run this method in the cron to insert value in the user table, will it get the same value result (200) at the 35th day?

Comment: You want to generate one value per day?

Comment: Yes exactly, and the total value on the 35th day should be 200 as the goal is 200.

Comment: dear are you there? Can you please do the further? I will be really thank ful to you.

Comment: Then it gets more complicated. I edited my answer. Now it generates new random value every day based on previous values. If actual average is bigger than desired then new value has more chances to be lower than desired average. The last value is just `200-array_sum($prev_values)`.

Comment: For this way, I have to save the value of the day in the table as previous value and then for each day I will have to call previous value from the table to get this method. Right? Yet it is more complicated now but I am more near to success and this is because of you.

Comment: You have to store all previous values and pass them as array `$prev_values`. You can also store sum of previous values, but then you have to replace `array_sum($prev_values)` with the `$prev_sum` and `array_sum($prev_values)/count($prev_values))` change to `$prev_sum/($day - 1)`.

Comment: And what If I inserr only one last value and then do substraction on the total of 200 with the last value and then apply the method for substracted value from 200 for the 2nd day and do the same for the each next day? Is it a good idea?

Comment: I'm not sure. Write code an check outputs. I think that generating values based on all previous values is more accurate.

Comment: I have marked your answer as answerd because you helped a lot. But I still have confusion. How can I store all 35 days values in the table after generating all the values? What is the best idea to give user different values on each day but the total sum of all given values on the 35th day should be same as 200. Yet you've given an answer that is probably more near to this but there is still some points to clear more. If you have abother idea OR you can make this method more clear and easy that would be really helpful for all of us. Thank you